# SQL Group based on individual row chaining to another individual row

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, sql-server-2014

I don't quite know how to ask this question better than this. Effectively I have a transaction table. This table per customer has 1 to many rows of transactions for that customers. Per row, it marks the customer ID of the previous customer that occurred before it. For example:

```
Cust_ID   Tran_Type   Prev_ID
10        A           9
10        B           9
9         T           7
9         A           7
8         B           ~
8         A           ~
7         T           ~
```

In this example, cust 7 is the starting customer for the day for an individual using this program. They then started working on customer 9 and then finally customer 10. In addition, for another individual they started with customer 8 and didn't do another transaction the entire day. The two groups I'd expect is group A which is comprised of customer 7, 9, 10 and group B comprised of customer 8 only.

I'm honestly stumped on this one. Does anyone have any advice? I'm fairly certain I want to start by grouping on the unique customer ID's and previous ID's which will give me:

```
Cust_ID   Prev_ID
10        9
9         7
8         ~
7         ~
```

At this point though I'm not sure how else to do it using vanilla sql. Thanks.

Comment: which sql version?

Comment: SQL version 2014

Comment: And what does the result set look like?

Comment: Something like:
- 1, 7
- 1, 9
- 1, 10
- 2, 8

The - indicates a new row and the 1 and 2 are basically grouping keys which group the individual customer keys

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This doesn't make much sense to me. Is ~ supposed to represent NULL? Some actual ddl and data would be extremely helpful. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

should just be a `group by`

```
select 
  custid, prev_id
from transactiontable
group by custid,previd
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you'd start with the distinct rows. Then recursively go up from the records without previous transactions.

```
with pairs as
(
  select distinct cust_id, prev_id from transactions
)
, groups (cust_id, prev_id, grp, pos) as
(
  select cust_id, prev_id, row_number() over (order by cust_id), 1
  from pairs
  where prev_id is null
  union all
  select p.cust_id, p.prev_id, g.grp, g.pos + 1
  from pairs p
  join groups g on g.cust_id = p.prev_id
)
select cust_id, prev_id, grp
from groups
order by grp, pos;
```

REXTESTER demo: http://rextester.com/NZGLU84962

Comment: First off, thanks. Second, I'm now doing this and I see it actually work for specific customer ID's but for some reason if I let it run on the full dataset which is REALLY LARGE, 100's of millions of rows I keep getting a maximum recursion error. I've looked it up, and have pushed it up to 1000 and for some reason it still gets thrown. I'd like to see where the problem is occurring but from what I can tell, based on other properties I have available to me, there's nothing that should recur that many times.

Comment: I did find out that in my data set I had scenarios where the previous ID = current ID. I fixed this. 

I also found I have scenarios where the previous ID <> current ID but on the previous id it references the original current ID creating a circular join which is causing the join to blow up. It looks like you can't reference the existence of already inserted records though so now I'm trying to consider transaction dates to see if that will solve this.